# Using Parse C SDK with CC3200

Tags: c, json, parse-platform, sdk, embedded

I'm trying to use the Parse C SDK with a TI CC3200 WiFi Module and I have been able to successfully make requests with small strings that create an Object in my Parse Project. However now, I'm collecting 1000 samples on my WiFi Module and want to send all of them to Parse. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to properly create the JSON payload using an integer array of 1000 values?

Thanks in advance!